# Cannot create frame in Toplevel window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame, toplevel

I have 1 root window and a toplevel window, and I want to put stuff in a frame in the toplevel window. However, the frame (rather the label in it) appears in the root window.

Screenshot of the windows.

[image: Screen Shot]

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="label1").pack()

newWindow = Toplevel(root)

Label(newWindow, text="label2").pack()
frame2 = Frame(newWindow).pack()
Label(frame2, text="framelabel2").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you do not have a toplevel window. You have defined `tk()` twice and apply a mainloop top `root`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT oops, pasted my old code by accident, I just updated it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you need both labels in the same window? 
OR Do you need each label in a different window? 

It might be useful if you use the grid option to orient the frames instead of pack.

Comment: @ParvBanks The issue is a simple matter of applying the geometry manage on a new line for the container `frame2`.

Comment: Check my answer, I have used grid to align the labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pack `frame2` on a new line like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="label1").pack()

newWindow = Toplevel(root)

Label(newWindow, text="label2").pack()
frame2 = Frame(newWindow)
frame2.pack() # pack frame2 on new line here.
Label(frame2, text="framelabel2").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The reason your `framelabel2` label is getting placed on the root window is due to `frame2` being == to `None` as `pack()` returns `None`. Because you try to pack a widget to `None` tkinter defaults that widget to the root window in an attempt to place that widget somewhere.

Simple fix is to make sure you always do `pack()`, `grid()` or `place()` on a new line when it comes to defining frames or any container for that matter.

Comment: Or really just don't assign `.pack()`, `.grid()` or `.place()` to anything :) Anytime you do is bound to be a bad time.

Comment: @Idlehands `Anytime you do is bound to be a bad time`... this is not correct. It is perfectly fine to assign a geometry manager to widgets that are not going to be updates such as labels and buttons that do not need to be updated later in the code and I would argue that assigning a geometry manager to a new line for every widget is just unnecessary and adds lines of code for no good reason.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  `.pack()`... and such always return `None`, no? What would be the point to assign a name to this result? Sure the geometry manager is still executed but the assigned name is useless and surely just causes confusion very much like this case?

Comment: @Idlehands take readability into account. If I have `Button(root, text="go", command=go).pack()` it may not be clear what this button is doing in the code when reading the code later. However if you do `login_button = Button(root, text="go", command=go).pack()` then you clearly know what this button is for and do not need to pack it on a new line.

Comment: Easily remedied by a comment line, but I do see your point.  Just different ways of implementation I suppose.  I stand by my position but I won't argue for those who find this useful.  To each their own :)

Comment: I agree with @Mike-SMT that you should always separate widget creation from widget layout. In my experience, separating the layout (calling `pack` or `grid`) and grouping them together makes the code much easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need two frames in this case, just use `grid` to align the labels:
The `column`, `row` format also makes it easier to read & you also have other options such as `padx`, `pady`, `sticky` for more flexibility of design.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid()
root.title("Tkinter Window")  # Replace with anything else you want
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Label1").grid(column=0,row=0)
label2= tk.Label(root,text="Label2").grid(column=0,row=1)
root.mainloop()
```

You can learn more about `grid` [here](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

Comment: The OP's question includes the 2nd frame for a reason. The example they provided is a MVCE for the sake of the question but I am sure there is a good reason the OP is trying to use a frame in the toplevel window.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I understand that. 
However, I have just shared another way of getting the same result.

I had some struggle while trying to manage multiple items in the tkinter window & that's when I came across the 'grid' way of doing it. 

Maybe he is not aware of other options?

Comment: Well in this case its not an issue with `pack` vs `grid` and just an issue of order of assignment of the geometry manager. I do agree however on preferring to use grid. It is my go to.

Comment: @Mike-SMT In my case I need to create multiple lines for a form, which I’m doing with a simple if loop, so I used frames instead of a grid to avoid the need to enumerate the if loop and assign row numbers. Is that advisable?

Comment: @NathanTew you can do it like that but honestly if you are using a loop then you can use `for ndex, item in list` to manage grid rows. Its not much harder to do it with grid but that said if you want to use a frame and just simply pack everything in that frame it should do what you want and work fine.